# How do I proof that a particular sequence algorithm is always odd?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given the sequence
a<sub>1</sub>=1, a<sub>2</sub>=3, a<sub>k</sub>=a<sub>k-2</sub>+2a<sub>k-1</sub>
for all integers k >= 3

How do I show that:
for all integers n >= 1, given the sequence a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>k</sub> as defined above, a<sub>n</sub> is always odd.

I've tried to define odd/even sequence using the python code below but I'm unable to resolve the question:

```
def odd_even(n, k):
    x = list()
    i = 1
    while i < n: 
        x.append(i)
        i = i + 2
    i = 2
    while i < 2:
        x.append(i)
        i = i + 2
    
    return (a[k - 1])

# Driver code
n = 10
k = 3

odd_even(n, k)
```

Comment: You won't prove a general rule by providing examples, even millions of them. This is a maths question, not a programming one.

Comment: @Don'tAccept. What program is there to write?

Comment: Looking at the code, I think the real question here is, "Why doesn't my code work?".

Comment: Start the array with 2 elements: `a = list([1,3])` Loop starting at 2: `for i in range(2,n):` Compute the next element of the sequence: `a.append(a[i-2] + 2 * a[i-1])`

Comment: @user3386109. Now prove that the element at k=1e32 is odd

Comment: @MadPhysicist how do I proof that k=1e32 is odd?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That wasn't my point. You either missed, or decided to ignore my first comment. Look at OP's code. Run OP's code. The title asks one question, which you answered. The code asks a very different question, which you ignored.

Comment: @no, prove that a_(1e32) is odd. My point is that while your suggested program implements the recursion correctly, it can't handle anything past the size of your memory, which is necessarily finite.

Comment: @MadPhysicist And you have not understood, nor even tried to understand, a single thing that I've said.

Comment: @user3386109 OP's question in the title and the body are completely consistent. OP is showing some code and asking if it can be a proof somehow. The simple answer is that simple python code can't be used to prove the theorem. What part of the question am I not addressing?

Comment: @user3386109. I'm quite aware of your first comment, but it's based on nothing that's actually written in the question, so I can't accept it as a valid interpretation. You've built the rest of your comments on that basis, so there's not much to say.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's based on the code in the question. The code and the title are not consistent, because the code in the question does not compute the sequence that is described, nor does it compute anything even remotely related to that sequence.

Comment: @MadPhysicist And furthermore, it doesn't matter whether the sequence can be computed out to some arbitrary number that you have chosen. Many of the unsolved problems in mathematics have been tested out to the maximum values reachable by modern computers. Those experiments cannot prove the conjectures which they are exploring, but they can disprove them if they find a counter-example. And that's the value in writing the code. All I was doing was helping the OP get their code working. Whether you think that's worthwhile is irrelevant, and unimportant.

Comment: @user3386109. I completely agree with you, but I think that the code is a red herring

Answer (score 7):

You can't prove a theorem with code like that, although you can hopefully satisfy yourself that it holds true for some limited sample of inputs.

Something like this can be proved by induction. 1 is odd, and 3 is odd. The expression `a_k-2 + 2 a_k-1` is odd when `a_k-2` is odd since `2 a_k-1` is always even regardless of the parity of `a_k-1`. Since `a_1` is odd, every `a_2n+1` must be odd. Since `a_2` is odd, every `a_2n+2` must be odd. QED.